# How to debug Python code called from a C++ project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mixed-mode

I have a visual studio 2015 c++ project which calls a python module.

The following tutorial on microsoft website give a method to debug C++ code when it is called from a visual studio python project.

ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode

similarly is it possible to debug a python code which is being called by a C++ program

For example my C++ code is as follows

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#else
#include <python.h>
#endif
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Calling Python to find the sum of 2 and 2.\n");
    // Initialize the Python interpreter.
    Py_Initialize();

    // Create some Python objects that will later be assigned values.
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;

    // Convert the file name to a Python string.
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("sample");

    // Import the file as a Python module.
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // Create a dictionary for the contents of the module.
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    // Get the add method from the dictionary.
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "add");

    // Create a Python tuple to hold the arguments to the method.
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);

    // Convert 2 to a Python integer.
    pValue = PyLong_FromLong(2);

    // Set the Python int as the first and second arguments to the method.
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);

    // Call the function with the arguments.
    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    // Print a message if calling the method failed.
    if (pResult == NULL)
        printf("Calling the add method failed.\n");

    // Convert the result to a long from a Python object.
    long result = PyLong_AsLong(pResult);

    // Destroy the Python interpreter.
    Py_Finalize();

    // Print the result.
    printf("The result is %d.\n", result); std::cin.ignore(); return 0;

}
```

which calls a Python 3 code as follows

```
# Returns the sum of two numbers.
def add(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

While debugging I want to put a break-point a the following instruction in the python code

```
    c = a + b
```

so after I press F11 on reaching to the following instruction in the C++ code, visual studio should dive in the python code

```
PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided as a note at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode, which states that

> Mixed-mode debugging as described here is enabled only when you have a Python project loaded into Visual Studio. That project determines the Visual Studio's debugging mode, which is what makes the mixed-mode option available. If, however, you have a C++ project loaded (as you would when embedding Python in another application as described on python.org, then Visual Studio uses the native C++ debugger that doesn't support mixed-mode debugging.
>
> In this case, start the C++ project without debugging (Debug > Start without debugging or Ctrl+F5), and then use Debug > Attach to Process.... In the dialog that appears, select the appropriate process, then use the Select... button to open the Select Code Type dialog in which you can select Python as shown below. Select OK to close that dialog, then Attach to start the debugger. Note that you may need to introduce a suitable pause or delay in the C++ app to ensure that it doesn't call the Python you want to debug before you can attach the debugger.